# Spam friendly Mails how to?

Tags: email, spam, spam-prevention

Ho together,

are there any lists or guidlines how a good mail has to look like to avoid beeing spam detected?

I'm sending lots of mails and want a minimal spam score.

(and those aren't spam mails, I send learning mails)

Thanks for your tips

Comment: https://www.ftc.gov/tips-advice/business-center/guidance/can-spam-act-compliance-guide-business

Comment: more technical hints would be nice?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: For me its about programming because i need this for generating Mails out of a rails app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Send each email to a single recipient
- Avoid using bcc
- Don't send emails out in large batches, stagger them
- Use a third party service
- Ensure the content meets the guidelines of the FTC
- Ensure there is an unsubscribe link
- Don't send from a domain that offers free email accounts
- Use an SPF record

Comment: how do I add the unsubscribe link correctly? are there anny tags I should use?

Comment: The unsubscribe link should make it easy for the user to request removal from the list.  It can be a link to a form, like this:

**<a href="unsubscribe.php?email@example.com">Click here</a> to unsubscribe**, and that page can remove the email from the list.